# Alembic / Flask-migrate migration on Heroku runs but does not create tables

Tags: postgresql, heroku, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

I am attempting to deploy a Flask app to Heroku. I have pushed to Heroku and can access my login page but any call to the db gives an OperationalError:

```
2014-01-29T12:12:31.801772+00:00 app[web.1]: OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table: projects_project u'SELECT
```

Using Flask-migrate I can successfully run local migrations and upgrades:

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade None -> 4b56d58e1d4c, empty message
```

When I try to upgrade on Heroku using `heroku run python manage.py db upgrade` the upgrade appears to happen, but the Context impl. is now SQLite?:

```
(dev01)Toms-MacBook-Pro:dev01 kt$ heroku run python manage.py db upgrade
Running `python manage.py db upgrade` attached to terminal... up, run.9069 
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade None -> 4b56d58e1d4c, empty message
```

Running `Heroku pg:info` gives:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 0
PG Version:  9.3.2
Created:     2014-01-27 18:55 UTC
Data Size:   6.4 MB
Tables:      0
Rows:        0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

The relevant logs for the Heroku upgrade are:

```
2014-01-29T12:55:40.112436+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py db upgrade` by kt@gmail.com
2014-01-29T12:55:44.638957+00:00 heroku[run.9069]: Awaiting client
2014-01-29T12:55:44.667692+00:00 heroku[run.9069]: Starting process with command `python manage.py db upgrade`
2014-01-29T12:55:44.836337+00:00 heroku[run.9069]: State changed from starting to up
2014-01-29T12:55:46.643857+00:00 heroku[run.9069]: Process exited with status 0
2014-01-29T12:55:46.656134+00:00 heroku[run.9069]: State changed from up to complete
```

Also, `heroku config` gives me:

```
(dev01)Toms-MacBook-Pro:dev01 kt$ heroku config
=== myapp Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:               postgres://xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/da0jtkatk6057v
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL: postgres://xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/da0jtkatk6057v

where [xxx == xxx]
```

How is the Context impl. set? Apart from this obvious difference between working local and heroku, I can't work out what's happening or how I should debug. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL for the database is taken from the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` configuration in your Flask app instance. This happens in the `env.py` configuration for Alembic that was created in the `migrations` folder.

Are you storing the value of `os.environ['DATABASE_URL']` in the configuration before you hand over control to Flask-Migrate and Alembic? It seems you have a default SQLite based database that never gets overwritten with the real one provided by Heroku.

Comment: I am actually using [Flask-Heroku](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-heroku/) which is meant to take care of configuring the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI (I think). I will try a set-up without this and manually setting it from the os.environ.

Comment: Thanks Miguel this worked. I don't quite understand why before Heroku config appeared to show that the correct DATABASE_URL was set but it wasn't working. Nonetheless, I now have SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URI'] in both the alembic env.py file and in my app's settings.py file for Flask config working. Thanks for the help. Looking forward to your book!